# how to embed .swf (in html) so it can be visible in mobile browser?

Tags: html, embed, flash, embedding

I have a .swf file that is currently embed in my [Web site](http://www.uniorkomerc.com.mk) , i try to use this codes:

`<object data="media/images/animacija-mkd.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="843" height="240" style="undefined" id="Unior" name="Unior">
    <param name="movie" value="media/images/animacija-mkd.swf" />
    <!-- If flash is not installed -->
    <p>You need Adobe Flash Player to view this content</p>
    </object>`

Before that code i try to use:

```
<embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="media/images/animacija-mkd.swf" width="843" height="240" style="undefined" id="Unior" name="Unior" quality="high" wmode="opaque" bgcolor="#0655B8" />
```

But with both embed codes when i open the website from ipad or mobile chrome-firefox browsers it cant be loaded (visible), except from firefox where u must click on the banner where it sais: *"Tap here to activate plugin"*

I try using [Google Swiffy](https://www.google.com/doubleclick/studio/swiffy/) but when i convert my .swf file via google-swiffy its not looking good as it is now, its gettin slower to load and etc...

I also try to use CreatJS (in Adobe CS6 Flash Pro) but that way somehow my .fla file using background images, some text and etc.

Is there any other way to embed my .swf so it will be visible on smartphones or tablets ?

Answer (score 1):

iOS doesn't support Flash, so you need to use Html5.

maybe try [this](http://www.flash-banner-converter.com/),  but writing the html5 version by yourself is the best option :)